# How can Selenium (Python, Chrome) find web elements visible in dev tools, but not visible in page source?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click the first item in the menu in a webpage with Python3 using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html).

I manage to log-in and navigate to the required page using Selenium, but there I get stuck: it looks like Selenium can't find any element in the page beyond the very first `div` in `body`.

I tried to find the element by `ID`, `class`, `xpath`, `selector`... The problem is probably not about that. I thought it could be about an `iframe`, but the content I need does not seem to be in one.

I guess that the problem is that the element I need to find is visible in the devtools, but not in the page source, so Selenium just can't see it - does this make sense? If so, can this be fixed?

[image: Devtools]

[image: Page source]

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
self.driver.get("my site")

# log-in website and navigate to needed page
# [...]

# find element in page

# this works
first_div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app-wrapper")

# this does not work
second_div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app-wrapper > div.layout.flex.flex-col.overflow-x-hidden.h-display-flex.h-flex-direction-column.h-screen")
```

## Edit

The problem is most likely due to a dynamic webpage with parts of the DOM tree attached later on by a script. I downloaded a local version of `page.html`, **removed scripts**, and successfully found the sought-after element in the local page with

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pathlib import Path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

html_file = Path.cwd() / "page.html"

driver.get(html_file.as_uri())

my_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='my-title']")
```

The exact same `driver.find_element` query won't work on the online page. I'm trying to implement a [waiting condition](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) as suggested in Misc08's answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the XPath? specifically (inspect element, right click on the element in the inspection pane and select COPY-> FULL xpath)? not ideal for long term use as it's sensitive to design changes; but it may help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Tried, unsuccesfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess that the problem is that the element I need to find is visible
> in the devtools, but not in the page source, so Selenium just can't
> see it - does this make sense? If so, can this be fixed?

No, this does not make sense, since Selenium is executing a full browser in the background like you are using when you investigate the page source with the devtools.

But you have some options to narrow your problem. The first thing you can do, is to print the source the webdriver is "seeing" in this moment:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

If you see the elements you are looking for in the page source, than you should try to improve your selector. It is helpful to go down the DOM step by step. Look for an upper element in the page tree first. If this works, try to find the next child element, then the next child, and so on. You can check if selenium found the element like this:

```
try:
   myelement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content')
   print("Found :)")
except NoSuchElementException:
   print("No found :(")
```

By the way, i think your CSS selector is by far to complex, just use on CSS class, not all of them:

```
second_div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app-wrapper > div.layout")
```

But there might be the case, where the elements you are looking for, are not present in the page source from the beginning on. Dynamic webpages getting more and more popular. In this case parts of the DOM tree are attached later on by a script. So you have to wait for the execution of the scripts, before you can find this "dynamic" elements. One dirty and unreliable option is to just add a sleep() here. Much better is to to use an explicit waiting condition, see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks, the problem is likely about dynamic content (see edited question), I'll try with Waits.

Comment: A simple test with sleep() worked! Thanks!